# Testing of even easy behaviour leads to a jungle of testing functions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, mstest

Until today I had a hard time with unit testing. For this reason I just started to read a book ["The art of Unit Testing"](https://livebook.manning.com/book/the-art-of-unit-testing-second-edition/chapter-1).
The author states that each "unit of work" has entry and exit points and that there should be a unit test for each exit point.
An "exit point" could be:

- A return value of a function (also an exception)
- A state change (for example of a class property)
- A third party system called (E-Mail service)

The entry point is usually a function call.

I was now eager to try this in one of my examples and I was successful. But for a price that I cannot accept.  My tests are a huge amount of functions and I would like to get your opinion about them.

The test class I want to use is easy:

```
public class RoleAssignement
{
    public string RoleId { get; }
    public string EnterpriseId { get; }
    public List<string> SiteIds { get; }

    public RoleAssignement(string roleId, string enterpriseScopeId)
    {
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(roleId);
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(enterpriseScopeId);
        Ensure.ThrowIfIdNotValid(roleId);
        Ensure.ThrowIfIdNotValid(enterpriseScopeId);

        RoleId = roleId;
        EnterpriseId = enterpriseScopeId;
    }

    public RoleAssignement(string roleId, List<string> siteScopeIds)
    {
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(roleId);
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(siteScopeIds);
        Ensure.ThrowIfIdNotValid(roleId);
        foreach(var id in siteScopeIds)
        {
            Ensure.ThrowIfIdNotValid(id);
        }
        RoleId = roleId;
        SiteIds = siteScopeIds;
    }
}
```

You can see that I have just three properties. One of them (RoleId) must be set always. The other two parameters should be exclusively set (if one is null, the other must be set and vice versa).

In the language of the book I have two "entry points" - my two constructors.

But I have ten exit points that are:

```
1 If roleId is null for the first constructor, an exception should be thrown.  
2 If roleId is null for the second constructor, an exception should be thrown.  
3 If enterpriseScopeId is null for the first constructor, an exception should be thrown.  
4 If siteScopeId is null for the second constructor, an exception should be thrown.  
5, 6, 7, 8 If any of the four parameters have an invalid id, an exception should be thrown.  
9 If the first constructor was called with the correct parameters, RoleId and EnterpriseId should be set but SiteIds should be null.  
10 If the second constructor was called => vice versa.
```

If I write my unit tests now, I get a long list of testing functions - one of each exit point. I pasted this in the end of my question.

The thing is: Am I really on the right way here? I have a very easy test class now and the tests for it seem to explode in a huge jungle of tests.
Testing each possible exit point with its own function will slow me down in my coding and because the tests are testing such an *easy behaviour* they are also worthless for me.

Or are they?

But what will happen if I start to test the more complicated things? I will have a project with 1000 lines of production code and 10000 lines of tedious test functions.

I think I misunderstood something, but I don't know what I misunderstood. Or am I okay with my tests and I have to live with this from now?

Here is my testing code - all tests are passing. I even wrote them following TDD:

[image]

Testing code: ~100 lines
Production code: ~30 lines

Really?

```
using CP.Admin.Core.SDK.ValueObjects;
using DataHive.Validations.Exceptions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CP.Admin.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class RoleAssignementTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementFirst_NullRoleIdParameter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement(null, "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc");
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementFirst_InvalidRoleIdParameter_ThrowsIdNotValidException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("invalidId", "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc");
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<IdNotValidException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementFirst_NullEnterpriseScopeIdParameter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                string param = null;
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", param);
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementFirst_InvalidEnterpriseScopeIdParameter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", "invalidId");
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<IdNotValidException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementSecond_NullRoleIdParameter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                var param = new List<string> { "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc" };
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement(null, param);
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementSecond_InvalidRoleIdParameter_ThrowsIdNotValidException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                var param = new List<string> { "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc" };
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("invalidId", param);
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<IdNotValidException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementSecond_NullSiteScopeIdParameter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                List<string> param = null;
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", param);
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementSecond_InvalidSiteScopeIdParameter_ThrowsIdNotValidException()
        {
            Action useConstructor = () =>
            {
                var param = new List<string> { "invalidId" };
                var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", param);
            };
            Assert.ThrowsException<IdNotValidException>(useConstructor);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementFirst_ParametersAreOkay_AllValuesAreCorrect()
        {
            var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc");
            Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.RoleId);
            Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.EnterpriseId);
            Assert.IsNull(roleAssignement.SiteIds);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void RoleAssignementSecond_ParametersAreOkay_AllValuesAreCorrect()
        {
            var param = new List<string> { "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc" };
            var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", param);
            Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.RoleId);
            Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.SiteIds);
            Assert.IsNull(roleAssignement.EnterpriseId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you recognize, going down this road will be very painful. Because wanting to assert for each possible case (every parameter value + every possible combination) will require (as you saw) more work than making the actual production code to work.

All of this because you are orienting tests regarding **data**.

If you consider testing the **behavior** of the system instead, you can break free from a lot of implementation details and focus on a higher level.

Considering behavior, the only one that I can eventually see is

> The other two parameters should be exclusively set (if one is null, the other must be set and vice versa).

It corresponds to scenarii 9 and 10 according to your numerotation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RoleAssignementFirst_ParametersAreOkay_AllValuesAreCorrect()
{
    var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc");
    Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.RoleId);
    Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.EnterpriseId);
    Assert.IsNull(roleAssignement.SiteIds);
}

[TestMethod]
public void RoleAssignementSecond_ParametersAreOkay_AllValuesAreCorrect()
{
    var param = new List<string> { "62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc" };
    var roleAssignement = new RoleAssignement("62500ac55988223c8b9b28fc", param);
    Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.RoleId);
    Assert.IsNotNull(roleAssignement.SiteIds);
    Assert.IsNull(roleAssignement.EnterpriseId);
}
```

Now the test codebase has a significant smaller proportion than before comparing to the production codebase, which is a better compromise because it tests the most important thing at a greatly reduced price (both in implementation and maintenance).

## Going further

Let me allow you to see something that you may never has thought would be possible. `RoleAssignment` could require **no tests** and still enforce the same rules as the one you want by better using the type system.

Consider the following code:

```
public class RoleAssignement
{
    public Id RoleId { get; }
    public Either<Id, List<Id>> RelatedIds { get; }

    public RoleAssignement(Id roleId, Either<Id, List<Id>> relatedIds)
    {
        RoleId = roleId;
        RelatedIds = relatedIds;
    }
}
```

I used a pattern called [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) to get rid of [primitive types](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession). These value objects (`Id` and `Either`) encapsulate all the validation for a Id to be considered valid. When given to `RoleAssignement` constructor, you then know for sure that you are handling correct values. No more tests needed for `RoleAssignement`, the type system already enforce your constraints !

You can then extract tests from your scenarii to test only value object construction **once**. Which means that even if `Id` is used everywhere through the codebase, it requires only to test once.

Comment: Thanks - well, throwing an exception if something is not in the correct format (the id) is also some kind of "behaviour" for me. But its an easy beahaviour. So you would state that my example is following the text book, but in practice I should not always follow the text book. Only for the "more important" logic that is the exclusive null rule I defined in the two tests you left over?

Comment: @DavidMason I say that testing such trivial behavior (as throwing an exception in case of null value) cost too much regarding the benefits and is not worth it. In short, one generally test methods behavior (the kind of behavior that "does the real job") and trust that constructors correctly do the variables assignment.

Comment: So I would also "hurt" TDD approaches here? Because I am actually not allowed to write the line "Ensure.ThrowsIfNull..." without first writing a test that shows I failed. So the official best practices can be "relaxed" in the moment I do not have enough benefit - like in my case?

Comment: @DavidMason TDD is a good practice but whenever a good practice is elevated to dogma (I consider having a test for each production code line a dogma) it does more damage than benefit. In my opinion it is perfectly fine to "relaxe" the approach for constructors but still keep it for methods.